# string Parallel search in MS word documents without opening it

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I'm doing a parallel search for searching a string in all Word documents (.doc) without opening it then list all returning files in a listbox.
I have a large number of files (1000 docs) in the folder.
When using `foreach` only, **it takes a long time** so I'm trying `parallel.foreach`.

When using `Parallel.Foreach` it returns 3 files only into the listbox then stops searching!

**CODE**

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(p1, "*.doc",    SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => (File.GetAttributes(file) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0).ToArray();

Parallel.ForEach(files, (f, loopState) =>
{
    qefl = WaitForm1.qafl;
    if (f.Trim().StartsWith("~"))
    {
        loopState.Stop();
    }
    if (qefl == 1)
    {
        loopState.Stop();
    }
    try
    {
        string str = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);
        string pt = Path.GetFullPath(f);
        label2.Text = pt;
        wordApp.Visible = false;
        wordfile = wordApp.Documents.Open(pt, ReadOnly: true, PasswordDocument: "password", Visible: false);
        int docc = wordfile.Paragraphs.Count;
        Range rng = wordfile.Paragraphs[docc].Range;
        rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
        object matchCase = false;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundsLike = false;
        object matchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = false;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;
        if (rng.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord, ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
        {
            FileSearch sh = new FileSearch();
            sh.FullPath = pt;
            sh.FileName = str;
            list.Add(sh);
        }
        rng.Select();
        wordfile.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordfile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
});

listBoxControl4.DataSource = list;
listBoxControl4.DisplayMember = "FileName";
listBoxControl4.ValueMember = "FullPath";
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Where is the problem?
2. Is there any way to make the search faster?

Comment: Well, you call `loopState.Stop();`, so it stops. Even if it did not, you have a shared `wordApp` object, so you make the whole thing much slower, because now calls from different threads must be marshaled to the main Word thread.

Comment: So, i should create wordApp object inside this thread before wordfile ?

Comment: I removed `loopstate.stop();` but still stopped.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "without opening it"? Apparently you have to open the file to search it (which your code also does). To address your problem: You won't benefit from using a parallel loop here because you are automating the same Word instance, so you won't use multiple CPU cores.

Comment: I mean without opening it to user and my code do it. Is there anyway to accelerate it ?